# How to parse specific URL?

Tags: php, url, atom-feed, rss-reader, simplepie

I try to use a specific `Atom` url with `SimplePie` but it does not work:

```
http://cat.internetbrokerproject.be/ibpcatalog/Feed/CatalogAtomFeed.svc/DigestedCatalogItems?$filter=SecureGuid%20eq%20'D8053C8D-4F92-4F27-9ED4-492E05C4D1CA'
```

I think the problem comes from the filter in the url...

```
$filter=SecureGuid%20eq%20'D8053C8D-4F92-4F27-9ED4-492E05C4D1CA'
```

someone would have an idea how to solve it please?

Comment: For the title: [**parse_url**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: the solution was to put a \ in front of $filter

Comment: @KérimosKai: You can create an answer (and accept it) to mark this question as solved.

Comment: `$` is a reserved ​character for URLs and should be encoded as `%24`